# FTP Client: Connection Reset, Can't Close Connection Until Application Quits

Tags: c++, tcp, ftp-client

**Overview**

In c++ (gcc-c++ 6.3.1) on Fedora 24 x86_64 using the standard sockets API, I am making a basic FTP client based on a select few components of [RFC-959](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt). I am running into the occasional problem that when receiving or sending data to a server, the data connection gets reset. I have no trouble closing the socket and continuing execution in the case of a data read, but my program trips up quite seriously when performing a write (such as with `put`/`STOR`).

There is a lot of code in this program so far, so I will include the most relevant parts in my answer and attempt to abstract the rest. If additional segments of code are needed, I will add them by request.

**Detailed Process**

Assume that the control connection is already functional and a user is authenticated.

1. I query passive mode to the server (`PASV`).
2. I receive passive response (227).
3. I open the data connection given the response's IP and port number.
4. I query a store request to the server (`STOR`)
5. I receive store approval (150)
6. I call send() for the first time, sending some of the data, but -1 is returned.
7. The `errno` value is verified equal to `ECONNRESET`
8. I attempt to close the socket
9. I read the control connection for the confirmation from server (226)

**Observations**

When attempting to close the connection in step 8 above, I have tried a few different things.

`shutdown(fileDescriptor, [any flag])`
returns -1, `ENOTCONN`/107, Transport endpoint is not connected.

`close(fileDescriptor)` returns 0 for success (occasionally I have seen `ECONNRESET` here too).

This behavior does not change when setting `SO_LINGER` to immediately close. In fact, the **most interesting** part is that after the server sends an `Rst` packet to me, my client never sends its own `Rst` or `Fin` until I terminate the program.

Enabling TCP_NODELAY to disable Nagle's algorithm doesn't change anything.

**Packet Watch: Standard FTP Client**

This is observing packets transferred on the standard FTP client that comes with most unix operating systems.

```
Packet         Direction  Purpose
ftp: PASV      -->        Client prompt for passive mode
ftp: 227       <--        Server approve passive mode
  tcp: Syn     -->        Client initiate handshake for data connection
  tcp: Syn+Ack <--        Server acknowledge handshake
  tcp: Ack     -->        Client acknowledge acknowledgement
ftp: STOR      -->        Client prompt to store file
ftp: 150       <--        Server approve of store request
  tcp: Rst+Ack <--        Server warns that connection is closed/reset
  tcp: Fin+Ack -->        Client closes connection
  tcp: Ack     -->        Client acknowledges server
ftp: 226       <--        Server sends response that file upload done
```

**Differences On My Client**

If you observe the same transaction from my client, the `Fin`+`Ack` or `Rst` packets is never sent when `close()` or `shutdown()` is called.

After this data connection fails to close, the control connection refuses to send any more responses, which causes all future commands to hang up. But once I close the program, resets are sent on all open connections, and the connections close.

Does anyone know of any obvious troubles I might be running into when trying to terminate the data connection? Why doesn't shutdown() or close() actually close the socket, and how can I force it to not return until it succeeds in doing so?

Comment: `shutdown()` isn't supposed to send resets, and nobody can send anything on a connection that has already been reset. All you can do with that socket is close it.

Comment: @EJP I have observed resets as well as a FIN and FIN+ACK in the past. Neither are happening in this case. The packets to close a connection are simply never sent until the program terminates. Forceful termination and graceful termination have the same result.

Comment: You may have observed resets from `close()`. Not from `shutdown()`. A `shutdown()` with `SHUT_WR` is only supposed to half-close the connection, and RST doesn't do that. In any case it isn't actually specified to send anything in particular, let alone FIN *or* RST, so there is still no 'supposed' about it.